# Create index in Mysql for string and datetime

Tags: mysql, indexing

I've got a table with almost 10 mill. rows and it contains a *reference (varchar20)* and *date_created(datetime)* columns. The table has two indexes on these columns.

By checking the slow_queries log, we've detected a very very slow query that is used very often:

```
...WHERE reference LIKE '%SOME_TEXT%' ORDER BY date_created
```

Now it is mandatory to improve the query time.

I've read that the best way would be a multiple index on these columns, something like this:

```
create index ref_date on my_table (reference, date_created)
```

But I would like to know if there's a better way to create this index or set a specific index type in order to make it perfect for the beforementioned query.

Thank you very much, guys!

Comment: Using a wildcard at the start (`LIKE '%SOME_TEXT%')` means the index on that column can't be used, so you won't get any performance increase by adding a new one. If you can remove that leading wildcard (`'SOME_TEXT%'`), your existing index can be used and you also will not need an additional one. The only way to improve the performance with wildcards at both ends would be to switch to a full text index, which adds a layer of complexity and may or may not improve performance depending on your specific data and searches.

Comment: We may remove that starting wildcard. I'll do some tests on Monday just to check if using current table state, time is reduced without that wildcard. Thanks!

Comment: Removing the left wildcard will allow the existing index to be used, which will drastically increase performance. Not quite as much as being able to remove both wildcards, but drastically nonetheless.

Comment: With the trailing wildcard, the second column in the index will not be used.  Still, it is OK to keep the composite index for situations where the trailing wildcard is not used.

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested, we removed the starting wildcard and searches now go faster.
We also added some indexes in numeric columns, improving the overall performance. Thank you all!